# React Router useRouteLoaderData TypeScript Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am using React Router to handle fetching data and passing it to components.

I am seeing a TypeScript error stating `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; value: string; }'.`

It seems like the error is happening because `reasonTypes` is unknown before the data is fetched.

Is don't really see why this is an error though. Once the data exists I want to make sure it is the correct type, but before the data is fetched I don't want to be making this check.

Here is my code declaring this variable

`let reasonTypes: {name:string value:string} = useRouteLoaderData('root')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [useRouteLoaderData](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/fdadc703f97d2feda562f4365f9fbd2ed5d6f4a9/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L925C1-L930C2) hook's return type is `unknown`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns the loaderData for the given routeId
>  */
> export function useRouteLoaderData(routeId: string): unknown {
>   let state = useDataRouterState(DataRouterStateHook.UseRouteLoaderData);
>   return state.loaderData[routeId];
> }
> ```

You can cast the returned data to the type you require.

Examples:

```js
const reasonTypes = useRouteLoaderData('root') as { name: string; value: string; };
```

```js
type Data = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
};

...

const reasonTypes = useRouteLoaderData('root') as Data;
```